# Display max(date) based on the id having multiple records

Tags: database, oracle

I want to display all the records based on the max(date) based on the each id with multiple records. For example if id=1 has 5 records and id=2 has three records. I just want to display all the records having max(date).

```
id       date             name   
1        15-sep-2016      hari
1        15-oct-2017      raj
1        15-sep-2015      xyz
2        14-aug-2017      abc
2        14-jun-2016      123
3        19-aug-2016      789
3        17-aug-2015      fff
```

I want to display records as shown below

```
id       date             name   
1        15-oct-2017      raj
2        14-aug-2017      abc
3        19-aug-2016      789
```

thank you

Comment: Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve] that can be useful to improve your question

Answer (score 2):

One way could be the following:

```
select *
from (
        select id, name, "date", row_number() over(partition by id order by "date" desc) as RN
        from yourTable
     )
where RN = 1
```

The inner query computes the rownumber of every row, based on `date desc`; the external one simply gives the row with the date in first position, that is the rows where with the maximum `date` for every value of `id`.

As an aside, you should better avoid using reserved words such as `date` for your columns

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, date_field, name from your_table_name primary_table where date_field = (
    SELECT MAX(date_field) from your_table_name AS secondary_table where primary_table.id = secondary_table.id GROUP BY secondary_table.id
) GROUP BY primary_table.id order by primary_table.id
```

In above query 'your_table_name' is the name of your table and date_field is the column name of your table's date column on which you need to find out max date per user.

Comment: I'm gettin the following error "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: I had added mysql query, if you need query for oracle then you need to alter it... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
with max_dt
as 
(
select t1.*
,dense_rank() over (partition by id order by date desc )  rnk
from table1 t1
 )
 select id,date,name  from max_dt
 where rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of requirement can be solved without subqueries:

```
select id, max(dt) as dt, 
           max(name) keep (dense_rank last order by dt) as name
from   table_name
group by id
order by id;
```

Don't use reserved words ("date") for column names, that only invites trouble.